# Spring Security 3.2 xml configuration in version 3.2

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to update my Spring Security version from 3.0 to 3.2. Following is the current config:

```xml
<security:http auto-config="true" realm="Domaine XXX" access-denied-page="/jsps/login/access-denied.action">
    <security:http-basic />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsps/i18n/**" filters="none" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/Action1.action" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/Action2.action" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/Action3.action" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/Result.action" filters="none" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/isalive.html" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/layout/**" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/acc.action" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/loadLoginCombo*" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/access-denied.action" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/logout.action" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.js" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.css" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.ico" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.gif" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.jpg" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/setLocale.action*" filters="none" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />

    <security:logout logout-url="/logout.action" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout.action" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/index.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/access-denied.action" default-target-url="/pageBlank.action" />

    <!-- security:concurrent-session-control max-sessions="5" exception-if-maximum-exceeded="true" / -->
</security:http>
```

When I host the application , I get the following message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The use of "filters='none'" is no longer supported. Please define a separate  element for the pattern you want to exclude and use the attribute "security='none'".

What exact changes should I make to conform to Spring Security 3.2 standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spring Security 3.1 `filter="none"` is not supported anymore, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ftn.d5e1027):

> [[4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d5e1027)] The use of multiple `<http>` elements is an important feature, allowing the namespace to simultaneously support both stateful and stateless paths within the same application, for example. The previous syntax, using the attribute `filters="none"` on an `intercept-url` element is incompatible with this change and is no longer supported in 3.1.

You have to use `<http>`, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d5e1027):

> From Spring Security 3.1 it is now possible to use multiple `http` elements to define separate security filter chain configurations for different request patterns. If the `pattern` attribute is omitted from an `http` element, it matches all requests. Creating an unsecured pattern is a simple example of this syntax, where the pattern is mapped to an empty filter chain [[4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ftn.d5e1027)]. We’ll look at this new syntax in more detail in the chapter on the Security Filter Chain.

and [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-chains-with-ns):

> **13.6 Advanced Namespace Configuration**
>
> As we saw earlier in the namespace chapter, it’s possible to use multiple `http` elements to define different security configurations for different URL patterns. Each element creates a filter chain within the internal `FilterChainProxy` and the URL pattern that should be mapped to it. The elements will be added in the order they are declared, so the most specific patterns must again be declared first. Here’s another example, for a similar situation to that above, where the application supports both a stateless RESTful API and also a normal web application which users log into using a form.
>
> ```xml
> <!-- Stateless RESTful service using Basic authentication -->
> <http pattern="/restful/**" create-session="stateless">
>     <intercept-url pattern='/**' access="hasRole('REMOTE')" />
>     <http-basic />
> </http>
>
> <!-- Empty filter chain for the login page -->
> <http pattern="/login.htm*" security="none"/>
>
> <!-- Additional filter chain for normal users, matching all other requests -->
> <http>
>     <intercept-url pattern='/**' access="hasRole('USER')" />
>     <form-login login-page='/login.htm' default-target-url="/home.htm"/>
>     <logout />
> </http>
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. It is working now!